# How to address window content not scaled properly (appears in the lower left corner)

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm testing some software that uses an old version of `OGRE` and `wxWidgets 3.1.5.1`, and one thing I notice is when I build my app with `wxWidgets 3.1.5`, all of the application appears in the lower left corner. However, when I use `wxWidgets 3.0.5`, everything appears normally but doesn't support macOS Dark mode, so I'm sticking with `wxWidgets 3.1.5.1`. So, here is the code:

```cpp
    wxString title;
    title = wxT("Test Software");
    SetTitle(title);
    SetClientSize(width, height);
    SetExtraStyle(wxWS_EX_PROCESS_IDLE);
    SetBackgroundStyle(wxBG_STYLE_PAINT);
```

All of these functions are treated as it is accessed through `wxFrame`.

The width is 640 and the height is 480, and it appears as such when I screen shot it. The window itself is too big, and is about 1280x960, which makes sense as the content only takes up a quarter of the window. Yes, I could change the variable so the new width and new height are what I previously mentioned but it makes the window too big and the content appear strange.

The code is meant for wxWidgets 3.0, but is slightly broken on 3.1. I've tried some functions like `ClientToWindow`, the solution from here https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/issues/17391 (I'm using cocoa, not OpenGL). I've also tried comparing the code from the wxWidget window/frame files without succession.

Ogre code:

```cpp
    params["vsync"] = "true";
    params["vsyncInterval"] = "1";
    params["externalWindowHandle"] = getOgreHandle();
    mRenderWindow = Ogre::Root::getSingleton().createRenderWindow(name, width, height, false, &params);
    mRenderWindow->setActive(true);
    mRenderWindow->windowMovedOrResized();

// on size event:

mRenderWindow->windowMovedOrResized();
```

Comment: could you please post a screenshot of you monitor when the app is running? Also, are you using sizers? If not - you should.

Comment: The only sizer I'm using for the `wxFrame` is `wxDefaultSize`, aka `wxSize(-1,-1)`. I don't think I need an actual sizer. The only thing I'm displaying is the output from `(Ogre::Root).renderOneFrame()`, and nothing fancy. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/DFFaKTP.jpg

Comment: can you post a code of how you adding the OGRE window and do layout?

Comment: edited, not using a layout either... I have a feeling its more to do with wx than OGRE, or OGRE acting weird because of the new wx version.

Comment: I wanted to see how did you added OGRE window to the main frame. And the sizer code. Thx.

Comment: I set up an Ogre RenderWindow that takes on the size of my frame using `GetClientSize`, then I link it up so essentially I have an `OnIdle` event running and it triggers a piece of code containing `OgreRoot->renderOneFrame()`. I set the wxFrame size using `SetClientSize` and nothing else.

Comment: do use sizers? You probably should add OGRE window to a sizer and see how it will look like.

Comment: i don't use any sizers, what type of sizer should I use if it's just an ogre renderwindow with `mroot->renderOneFrame();`?

Comment: you don't have any other control there, right? Check the documentation and various samples/tutorials on how to use sizers. I think you will need a wxBoxSizer there.

Comment: I think wxFrame's dimensions including the unused area in the app thinks its 800x600 relative to a content scale factor. The RenderWindow or Viewport/Camera that I use to render a frame has dimensions half of that size for some reason, or wxFrame's actual dimensions are 1600x1200 then the Render is 800x600. `GetContentScaleFactor()` returns 2.`